# assembly - How to boot kernel that is appended end of kernel?

Tags: assembly, kernel, nasm, 16-bit, mbr

I am trying to boot my assembly kernel on assembly bootloader/MBR. 
I am reading kernel from offset 0x7e00 to offset 0x8000 (sector 1) into memory; and jumping offset 0x7e00. Why it is not jumps into my kernel?

```
; Boot.asm
[org 0x7c00]
[bits 16]

ReadDisk:
    push ax
    push bx
    push cx
    push dx

    mov bx, 0x0000
    mov es, bx
    mov bx, 0x0000

    mov ah, 0x02
    mov al, 0x01
    mov ch, 0x00
    mov cl, 0x02
    mov dh, 0x00
    mov dl, 0x80
    int 0x13
    jc ReadDisk
    jmp 0x7e00


times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

~~~~

```
; Kernel.asm
; Print dot on screen and hang
[org 0x7e00]
[bits 16]

mov ah, 0x0e ; BIOS teletype subfunction
mov al, '.'
int 10h
jmp $ ; hang

times 512 - ($ - $$) db 0 ; Fill sector.
```

Environment : NASM, QEMU, Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this use, but do you need to set up BH (page) and BL (color)?

Comment: No, I write without nor page nor color.

Comment: You're reading sector 2 to 0000:0000!

Comment: It seems to be looping, due to an error from int 13h.  Can you send the return value to a serial port to see why it fails?

Comment: How to do it, @donjuedo?

Comment: BIOS interrupt 14h, I think.

Comment: Where it will output?

Comment: please listen to @FrankKotler. You are also consuming stack space at each loop on INT13 error.

Comment: I changed 'mov bx, 0x0000' to 'mov bx, 0x7e00'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your last comment I can't make up which `mov bx, 0x0000` you replaced to fix the problem. Here's the solution:

```
mov bx, 0x0000
mov es, bx
mov bx, 0x7E00
```

In stead of risking endless retries you should abort when BIOS reports an error!
Preferably with a message.

Luckily you are doing all of this in an simulated environment because otherwise toying with the first harddisk (`mov dl, 0x80`) is never a good idea.

Comment: Building on this answer, it is wise to take notice of the value in `dl` when your code is called from BIOS.  This will tell you the drive that the system booted from which can save you a great deal of pain and troubleshooting... It may not be 0x80.

Comment: Should I save dl's value to variable??